# Отключение рекламы в приложении

Tags: android, android-billing

У меня в приложении есть межстраничная реклама и баннер в одной из активити. Хотелось бы реализовать платное отключение рекламы.

1. Я добавила файл IInAppBillingService.aidl в свой проект
2. Добавила необходимое разрешение в файл манифест
3. Обновила apk на сайте разработчика в Google и создала там "Ограниченный контент".

Подскажите пожалуйста каковы мои дальнейшие действия? Как реализовать саму покупку, как не показывать рекламу, если покупка была оплачена?

МЕЖСТРАНИЧНАЯ РЕКЛАМА у меня реализована так

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdRequest adRequesti;
    private InterstitialAd adMob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ***

        adMob = new InterstitialAd(this);
        adMob.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_i));
        adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adMob.loadAd(adRequesti);
    }

    private void showAds(Intent i, Context c) {
        final Intent intent = i;
        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE | NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            adMob.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
                adMob.show();
            } else {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            adMob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    adMob.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

А БАННЕР так

```
public class WordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Могу посоветовать вот эту [статью](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/05/implementing-remove-ads-in-app-purchases-in-android-tutorial-example/), посмотрите так же [тут](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121589/how-can-i-implement-a-disable-ads-purchase-in-my-game) и вот такой же [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323097/in-app-purchase-remove-ads).